# Checking if a file exist before loading it into webpage

Tags: php, wordpress, background

I've constructed a php function that changes background on a WordPress post based on what's specified in a custom field, for example red001 (that will load https://example.com/img/backgrounds/red001.jpg)

it took a long time, since I'm not so good at php, but it needs an improvement, which I need help to get to work.

this is the script, which once inserted in functions.php will handle the background.

```
<?php
// Set background from custom field via "rbpet_background_image" function
function rbpet_post_background() {

    if ( $background = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'usp-custom-background_image', true ) ) { 
$backgroundpre = "https://example.com/img/backgrounds/";
$backgroundpost = ".jpg";
$newbgurl = $backgroundpre . $background . $backgroundpost;
?>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { background-image: url( "<?php echo ($newbgurl); ?>")!important; }
        </style>
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'rbpet_post_background' );
```

as I wrote, it works, BUT,  if I now want to have a background in gif, png, or a movie?

I don't want to specify that in the custom fields, how do I do that?

I was thinking about someway to check if the .jpg file exist then load it, and if not, check if the .gif file exist then load it, and if not check if the .mp4 file exist.... is this possible so someway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a couple of hours to solve why it didn't work.

@Sebastian W did the main work with the script, I just changed the way it loaded the file

```
    // set background based on custom field in post
    function rbpet_post_background () {

        if ( empty( $background = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'usp-custom-background_image', true ) ) ) return;
        $base = "https://example.com/img/backgrounds/";
        $extensions = array( ".jpg" , ".gif" , ".mp4" );

        foreach ( $extensions as $ext ) {

            $file = $base . $background . $ext;
            $file_headers = 

@get_headers( $file );
            if ( $file_headers[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ) {
                $background_url = $file;
                break;
            }

        }



 if ( empty( $background_url ) ) return;

?>
    <style type="text/css">
            body { background-image: url( "<?php echo ($background_url); ?>")!important; }
        </style>
<?php
}

    add_action( "wp_head" , "rbpet_post_background" );
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be one way to do this.

```
function rbpet_post_background () {

    if ( empty( $background = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'usp-custom-background_image', true ) ) ) return;
    $base = "https://example.com/img/backgrounds/";
    $extensions = array( ".jpg" , ".gif" , ".mp4" );

    foreach ( $extensions as $ext ) {

        $file = $base . $background . $ext;
        $file_headers = @get_headers( $file );
        if ( $file_headers[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ) {
            $background_url = $file;
            break;
        }

    }

    if ( empty( $background_url ) ) return;

    wp_add_inline_style( "admin-checklist-handle" , 'body { background-image: url("' . $background_url . '")!important; }' );

}

add_action( "wp_head" , "rbpet_post_background" );
```

You could use file_exists instead of get_headers. This will be better in terms of performance. However, you will need to be sure, that $base is located on your server and you will need to use a path instead of URL.

Comment: How would it look if you where using file_exists? (The script)

Comment: So you mean the absolute path?

Comment: The code didn't work, not for me, nothing happened at all. When looking at source code, the page don't contain the script at all...

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't had a look in here for a while. Glad it worked out in the end! To answer your question: using file_exists only works for local files. For remote files get_headers is better. Would you mind marking my answer as correct?